# Will Microsoft Flow for SharePoint libraries work for all users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, microsoft-flow

I used Microsoft Flow and created a flow that copies document from one sharepoint library to another SharePoint library

I used the below template

[image]

It worked in one library. But when I replicated the same in another library it doesn't seem to get triggered, as i couldn't see any history for the new flow. 
I have write access to both libraries.

Also, when I create flow for a library, will it work only when I upload a document or is it applicable to all users?